# SSL certificates for different domain extensions

Tags: ssl

I have setup my site in a single webserver with different domain extensions, e.g.

https://mybusiness.com

https://mybusiness.com.au

https://mybusiness.co.nz 
....

and also I have subdomain(different websites in IIS) to do the backend stuff, e.g.

https://admin.mybusiness.com

https://admin.mybusiness.com.au

https://admin.mybusiness.co.nz

I am looking for to buy SSL certificate but not too sure which type will suit my case the most.

Should I buy one single domain SSL with Multiple Subdomains Supported SSL, or should I buy separate domain SSL for each with Multiple Subdomains Supported SSL certificates.

Answer (score 0):

> SSL certificates for different domain extensions...

I don't believe the CA posse will sell you a wildcard like `mybusiness.*` and `*.mybusiness.*`. At minimum, you'd have to demonstrate control of all possible domains, and you probably cannot do it.

The CAs and Browsers have gotten together and abide by self imposed requirements. See the [CA/B Baseline Requirements](https://cabforum.org/baseline-requirements-documents/). The rule of thumb is a wildcard should appear as the leftmost part of the FQDN. The IETF is a little sloppier, but people buy from CAs and not the IETF. So you have to play the the CA/B rules.

(Oddly, non-browsers parse by the IETF rules, so non-browsers can be made to accept certificates that are not valid by the standards they are issued against).

---

> Should I buy one single domain SSL with Multiple Subdomains Supported SSL,

I believe you should purchase one certificate that covers the applicable domain names under your control. You need to list all the domains under your control and apply with a request that lists them in the Subject Alternate Name (SAN) as a DNS name. The CSR might look like:

- CN = My Business, LLC
- SAN = DNS:mybusiness.com
- SAN = DNS:mybusiness.com.au
- SAN = DNS:mybusiness.co.zn
- SAN = DNS:*.mybusiness.com
- SAN = DNS:*.mybusiness.com.au
- SAN = DNS:*.mybusiness.co.zn

Placing a DNS name in the Common Name (CN) is deprecated and not be used. Hence the reason you put a friendly name.

---

If you don't mind one certifcate per domain (without wildcards), then [Starcom](https://cert.startcom.org/) will give you a Class 1 for free. Startcom is trusted by most mobile and desktop browsers. They offer wildcards too, but you have to buy them.